# A floating widget should appear after a phone call (when the app is closed)

Tags: java, android, class, service

I created a floating widget that works even when the app closed. In addition I have a class that is responsible for detecting incoming and outgoing calls on the device And send a suitable toast. it also works when the app is closed.
Now I want the floating widget to **appear** on the screen **when a call on the device ends**.
I tried to do this but the widget does not appear. **Both work separately, but not together**.

There are two classs:

-Creates the widget : FloatingViewService extends Service.

-Call Recognition: CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver.

**CallReceiver class**

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    // ^ detecting incoming and outgoing calls ^
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
           showToast(context,"Call started...");
        }
        else if(intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
            showToast(context,"Call ended...");
            //*****Activate the floating widget after the call ends.
            startWidget( context );
        }
        else if(intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
           showToast(context,"Incoming call...");
        }
    }

    //*****Activate widget
     void startWidget(Context cotx) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) { //Permission checks
            if (Settings.canDrawOverlays(cotx)) {
           //     Start  widget service
                startService( new Intent( cotx, FloatingViewService.class));
            }
        }
    }
    //*****Action: Start a particular service
    public ComponentName startService(Intent service) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

//Another action unrelated to my question

}
```

I believe the problem is related to the "startService" operation.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem for myself in a relatively simple way.
All I had to do was **delete "startService"** and **update "startWidget"** as follows:

```
    void startWidget(Context cotx) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) { //Permission checks
            if (Settings.canDrawOverlays(cotx)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(cotx,FloatingViewService.class);
                cotx.startService(intent);
                Log.i("Autostart", "started");
            }
        }
    }
```